# Xamarin forms: How to check a browser is open successfully in my webview

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin forms app, using webview I am loading a website with its IP. If the website loading is fail I want to redirect the user back to IP entering page and let him enter the correct IP. So how I can check the website is loading successfully or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shared project, you have the `Navigated` event from your Webview object:

```
WebView webView = new WebView ();
webView.Navigated += WebView_Navigated;

private void WebView_Navigated (object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    //your stuff
}
```

Comment: Can you tell, where this code check the app loads the website successfully? I am working on xamarin forms project.

Comment: @SreejithSree I misread and thought it was for Xamarin.Android, here is the one for Xamarin.Forms

Comment: I add your code and run the app. For fail to load the website I off the internet connection. But showing the usual webpage is not available message, not entering inside of the WebView_Navigated method.

Comment: @SreejithSree I didn't fully understand, but if you turn off your internet connection it won't be able to navigate and fire the Navigated event.

Comment: Without turn off, how I can test this?

Comment: You could use CharlesProxy and interrupt or delay the connection to a certain address